# alter some attributes of an html/xml string

Tags: android

I have some strings that are a sequence of html paragraphs:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong> strong text> <a href=\"skhf\">alink</a></p>
<p> another par </p>
```

I want to change paragraph and link style, so adding/removing attributes. Moreover I'd like to remove some paragraphs also, according to their content.
I guess I have first to convert this string in an xml structure and then revert it back to string right? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `yourString.replace(oldChar, newChar)` if there are not many changes

Comment: Maybe I can do it with replaceALL and a regular expression...I have to eliminate all <p> elements whose inner text is "UPDATE", mind that there could be some <strong> or <em> inner elements inside <p>..can you help me out?

Comment: can you give the example html code that you are trying to change?

Comment: And look at this library it might help you http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html